# Database design - using JSON to store info

Tags: mysql, json, database

I have a database listing campsites 
There is a main table tblSites that contains the unique data eg name, coordinates, address etc and also includes columns for each facility  eg, Toilet, Water, Shower, Electric etc where these are just 1=Yes, Null= no
This would be searched by something like

SELECT id FROM tblSites WHERE Water = 1 AND Toilets = 1

There is another related table tblLocations which contains location type (ie Near the sea, Rural, Mountains, By a river etc.
This means the table has a lot of columns and doesn't allow for easy updating if I want to add a new category. 
This would be included in a search like this

SELECT M.id, L.* FROM tblSites AS M 
LEFT JOIN tblLocation AS L ON M.ID = L.ID  WHERE M.water=1 AND L.river=1

What I am considering is adding a column eg facilities that would contain an json string of facilities as a numbered key eg [1,3,4,12] each of the numbers represents an available facility, and another column for locations in the same format eg [1,3,5]

THis does allow me to reduce the table size and add additional facilities or locations without adding extra columns but is it a good idea performance wise?

i.e. a search would now be something like

SELECT id FROM tblSites WHERE (facilities LIKE '%1,%' AND facilities LIKE '%4,%' AND locations LIKE '%1,%')

Is there a better query that could be used to see if the field contains a key number in the array string?

Comment: to use JSON type columns in `where` condition [see this documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) and use functions like `JSON_CONTAINS` @lifeson

Comment: You're making a bad situation even worse. Model your one-to-many relations as proper one-to-many relations, not by splitting them out over columns or by including JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is not working fine while using like '%1,%'.
if your `facilities` is string (`TEXT` or `varchar` ...) and searching value in stringed json array [2,3,12,21,300], `where facilities like '%1,%'` is true and matching with '21,' and if you want find `where facilities like '%300,%'` it never match that mentioned array!

So, searching json array in string format is rejected.

if your MySQL version is greater than 5.7.8, it supports native json as `JSON` type for columns.

When you store your data in json column in MySQL (by `JSON_INSERT()`) you're able to search them in `where` by `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(facilities,1)`

**But** the best solution is re-design your table structures and relations as @Robby commented below your question.

Comment: %1,%' does not match 21 !! note the comma. My database version does not support JSON data type. JSON data type is obviously a newer addition to the MySQL data type options with new functions to support the data type. WHy would these new features be added if they do not add benefit?

Comment: I repeat that %1,% match '21,' in that string, it's clear! If you like using like operation, create comma separated value that in start and end of string has extra ',' . So if your facilities is ",2,7,8,21," then '%,id,%' is safe usage.

Comment: If you have tables with many rows and many facilities and locations, you should use another table for storing facilities and locations relations to `tblSites`. If you want any suggestion or helps for this way, let me know. **but** if you want use facilities and locations column in tblSites as you mentioned in the question, let us know too. thank you @lifeson